# Prove convergence of this integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$$\int_0^\infty\frac1{(x^2+1)(\ln^2(x)+\pi^2)}$$

Prove the convergence of this integration.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

- At $+\infty$:
  $$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(\ln^2 x+\pi^2)}=o\left(\frac 1{x^2}\right)$$
- At $0$
  $$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(\ln^2 x+\pi^2)}\sim \frac{1}{\ln^2 x}=o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, "Sami" but please clarification for the convergence at the 0

Comment: For the second equality what's $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt x \ln^2x$?

Comment: limx→0 (√x (lnx)^2) =0

Comment: So $$\frac{1}{\ln^2 x}<\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$ for $x$ near of $0$.